# Website displaying green corrupted jpeg images on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, image-scaling, html-rendering

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUaS.jpg

Has anyone ran into this problem before? I seem to be getting corrupted images or bad rendering on Safari for iPhone while on Chrome it is fine. The website is http://thefinfan.com.

The reason might be because the images are large but are shrunk down by the responsive layout. So the image is still the full high resolution image but it is being forced down.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the images are just far too large. There's no need to have them anywhere near that file size, even for retina displays. Have a look at this article, which demonstrates that you get high quality retina display of images by giving them large dimensions but saving them at low quality:

http://blog.netvlies.nl/design-interactie/retina-revolution/

Comment: It's a responsive wordpress site though so the large images need to be displayed for desktop and the small images for iPhone. The problem is I don't know a good way of doing that dynamically within wordpress. 

Are you able to reproduce on an iPhone?

Comment: Your image file sizes currently are *way* too large for the desktop as well ... about 10-20 times larger than needed. If you saved them at 10% quality while leaving the dimensions the same (though I would reduce them, as they're way larger than needed) you'd still get the same visual result (I tested it myself). I did test on iPhone. I didn't get as much green as you, but I was connected via wi fi. The article I pointed you to deals with images for all devices. It's a one method fits all option—far better than the multi-image JS options people are throwing around at the moment, in my view.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll start lowering the quality of the images.